# @Transactional method call within @Transactional method (both with default propagation)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, jta, transactional

I have the following setting (it's an analogy), and the repository changes on methodB are not rollbacked. Propagations should be default = REQUIRED, so what could be the explanation?

Parent.java

```
@Transactional
public void methodA(){
   child.methodB();
   anotherMethodThatThrowsARuntimeException();
}
```

Child.java

```
@Transactional
public void methodB(){
   repository.save(entity)
}
```

First of all, is my understanding correct in that I should expected everything rollbacked?

Even if all this situation is happening when this code is wrapped under a `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)` test?

EDIT: Just for the sake of the resolution: the problem was that.SQL rollback was indeed at the end of of outer transaction but the managed context was not cleared so rollback from inner transaction was not visible

Comment: Your expectations are correct. But I can't reproduce the issue. Can you please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am trying to do some tests on where the exception is interpreted before something like this, first of all I wanted to know whether I am in the proper assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some database engines don't have support for transaction. First check your database engine. MyISAM engine of MySQL is an example for this case.